# Grow container when child grows using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Please take a look at the following layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="middleman">
    <div class="child">
      /* child can grow (height will expand) */
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above case, container's initial height is `100px` and child's initial height is `70px`. Upon some action, child's height becomes `300px`. In this case, how can I make the container grow its height?

Comment: It would do that automatically, unless there is something you haven't told us. A demo of the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Do you set `height` on `.container`, or `min-height`? Is the `.child` positioned `absolute` or `relative`? It would help to actually see your CSS.

Comment: try `min-height: 100px` instead of `height` on `.container`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-height` on container element.

```js
$('.child').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('height')
})
```

```css
.container,
.middleman {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.child {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.height {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="middleman">
    <div class="child">
      /* child can grow (height will expand) */
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```